# Non-principal ideal in ring $\Bbb Z×\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I finally started studying ring theory for my final and it seems like the above ring always has a principal ideal. Is this always the case?

So far the examples I've looked at are:

$\{(7a, 19b) \mid a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\}$

$\{(7a, 0) \mid  a ∈  \Bbb Z\}$

$\{(7a, b) \mid  a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\}$

$\{(a, 0) \mid  a ∈ \Bbb Z\}$

Comment: 1. Please use MathJax. [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). 2. Is $Z*Z$ meant to be the cartesian product? Because $*$ is not used for that. Use $\times$ (`\times`, when you use MathJax).

Comment: Will keep it in mind moving forward, thank you for the edit!

Comment: Not really because idk what PID are. Course hasn't gone that far yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, in general if two commutative rings $R_1$, $R_2$ are "principal ideal rings," i.e. every ideal is principal, then their product $R_1 \times R_2$ is a principal ideal ring as well.

The key is that every ideal $I \subseteq R_1 \times R_2$ decomposes as a product of ideals $I_1 \times I_2$ where $I_j \subseteq R_j$ are ideals. $I_j$ can be taken to be the image $\pi_j[I]$, where $\pi_j: R_1 \times R_2 \longrightarrow R_j$ is the projection map. Indeed, the containment $I \subseteq I_1 \times I_2$ is clear. On the other hand, let $(a, b) \in I_1 \times I_2$. Then $a \in \pi_1[I]$ so there is some $a' \in R_2$ such that $(a, a') \in I$. Similarly, there is some $b' \in R_1$ such that $(b', b) \in I$. Then write $(a, b) = (1, 0) (a, a') + (0, 1) (b', b) \in I$ as $I$ is an ideal of $R_1 \times R_2$. Hence, $I_1 \times I_2 \subseteq I \subseteq I_1 \times I_2$.

Thus, if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are principal ideal rings we can now write every ideal of $R_1 \times R_2$ as a product of principal ideals $R_1 a_1 \times R_2 a_2$. This will end up being $(R_1 \times R_2)(a_1, a_2)$. Indeed, we use the proof of the above paragraph and observe that $\pi_j[(R_1 \times R_2)(a_1, a_2)] = R_j a_j$. Then we can indeed write $(R_1 \times R_2)(a_1, a_2) = R_1 a_1 \times R_2 a_2$. Hence, every ideal of $R_1 \times R_2$ is principal.

Apply this to $R_1 = R_2 = \mathbb Z$, which is a PID.

Comment: awesome! thank you